# Gradle Tooling API - How to use Gradle wrapper?

Tags: gradle, gradlew, gradle-tooling-api

I've started using Gradle tooling API and found question:
Is there any way to use Gradle wrapper as Gradle installation from Tooling API?
I need to ignore any Gradle installation in the system and use Gradle wrapper for target project under Tooling API.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't this the default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to set this. This is the default behavior: tooling API will try to read `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` in your project to find appropriate distribution that will be used according to a test in https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/7dd276a91d9e22248306584afe04171fd86db529/subprojects/tooling-api/src/test/groovy/org/gradle/tooling/internal/consumer/DistributionFactoryTest.groovy#L44

Comment: Thanks, it works good. Have not found this behavior previously.

Answer (score 0):

you could set the installation to use manually and point it to your existing wrapper directory:

```
GradleConnector connector = GradleConnector.newConnector();
connector.useInstallation(new File("/Users/Rene/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.12-all/2apkk7d25miauqf1pdjp1bm0uo/gradle-1.12"));
```

Comment: Thanks, but this way is little bit "hardcoded" and not suitable for me.

Comment: well you could add some dynamic logic to resolve the path from "~/.gradle/wrapper"